# 45 degrees x axis labels in barplot

Tags: r, rotation, axis, label

I know this type of question has been posted several times, but I tried all different  suggestions and nothing works for me. I would like to have the x-axis labels on my bar plot positioned at 45 degrees. My code at the moment is like this:

```
barplot(t(all.vac_models01[1:28,3:4]), ylab = expression("Proportion of "*italic("R"^"2")),
las=2, cex.names = 0.9,
legend.text = gsub("prop_attributed_to_visit", "Intraindividual", 
gsub(pattern = "prop_attributed_to_patientID", 
replacement = "Interindividual", colnames(all.vac_models01[1:28,3:4]))), 
args.legend = list(x= 30, y = 1.3, xpd = T, horiz = T, bg = "white", bty ="o", box.lwd = 0))>
```

Comment: It in the R FAQ: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#How-can-I-create-rotated-axis-labels_003f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
x <- barplot(t(all.vac_models01[1:28,3:4]), ylab = expression("Proportion of "*italic("R"^"2")),
        las=2, cex.names = 0.9,
        legend.text = gsub("prop_attributed_to_visit", "Intraindividual", 
                           gsub(pattern = "prop_attributed_to_patientID", 
                                replacement = "Interindividual", colnames(all.vac_models01[1:28,3:4]))), 
        args.legend = list(x= 30, y = 1.3, xpd = T, horiz = T, bg = "white", bty ="o", box.lwd = 0),
        xaxt="n")
labs <- names(t(all.vac_models01[1:28,3:4]))
text(cex=1, x=x, y=-1.25, labs, xpd=TRUE, srt=45, pos=2)
```

Assigning the `barplot` call to `x` allows you to store the position of the labels.  Be sure to specify `xaxt="n"` so that the labels are not printed initially.